# using python to get the powershell result

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I want to design a GUI programme to callback some powershell's command result.
The problem is when the `cb_option_a` has been selected and click the execute botton, it is success to call the powershell and run the command.

However, it is not success to callback the result to the textarea box, it has the following error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'get-itemproperty
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | select setupstring,versionstring'
returned non-zero exit status 255
```

Other option of cmd command like `ipconfig` is success to callback. How can I fix that? 
The programme code:

```
option_a = IntVar()
option_b = IntVar()
option_c = IntVar()

def startpowershell():
    powershellcommand = command_gen()
    commandresult = runpowershellcommand(powershellcommand)
    txtarea_output.insert(INSERT, commandresult)


def command_gen():

    if option_a.get():
        command = "get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | select setupstring,versionstring"

    if option_b.get():
        command = "ipconfig"

    if option_c.get():
        command ="ping 127.0.0.1"

    command = command

    result = command
    return result

def runpowershellcommand(callpowershell):
    output = subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", command_gen()])
    output = subprocess.check_output(callpowershell, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=TRUE)
    txtarea_output.config(state=NORMAL)
    txtarea_output.insert(INSERT, output)
    txtarea_output.config(state=DISABLED)
    return output


lb_RT = Label(root, text="PowerShell:")
lb_RT.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

cb_option_a = Checkbutton(root, text="IIS ver.", variable=option_a)
cb_option_a.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

cb_option_b = Checkbutton(root, text="cmd command1", variable=option_b)
cb_option_b.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

cb_option_c = Checkbutton(root, text="cmd command2", variable=option_c)
cb_option_c.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

btn_run = Button(root, text="Execute", command=startpowershell)
btn_run.grid(row=8, column=3, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=E)

txtarea_output = Text(root, height=10, width=80, fg="red",bd=8)
txtarea_output.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)
txtarea_output.config(state=DISABLED)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

that line

```
subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", command_gen()])
```

won't work because `command_gen()` output is treated as a sole argument, and it is in fact several arguments. So `subprocess.call` quotes the argument, not what you want.

Moreover you're using a `|` so you'd have to activate `shell=True`

that line

```
output = subprocess.check_output(callpowershell, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=TRUE)
```

won't work because you're not prefixing it by `powershell.exe` (also: `TRUE` should be `True`)

Anyway, the `subprocess` lines are redundant:

```
output = subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", command_gen()])
output = subprocess.check_output(callpowershell, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

you want to do just one call, retrieving the output:

```
def runpowershellcommand(callpowershell):
    output = subprocess.check_output("powershell.exe "+callpowershell, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

That will work because there are no spaces in the arguments.

Aside: be careful here:

```
    command = "get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | select setupstring,versionstring"
```

works but you're lucky. It should be raw-string prefixed to avoid interpretation of escaped sequences by python:

```
   command = r"get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | select setupstring,versionstring"
```

Comment: how can i fix the CalledProcessError?

Comment: how stated in my answer: `def runpowershellcommand(callpowershell):
    output = subprocess.check_output("powershell.exe "+callpowershell, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`

Comment: i have try that, but it has a similar error here: `CalledProcessError: Command 'powershell.exe get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | select setupstring,versionstring' returned non-zero exit status 255`